# Sobre una función mandando un valor a otra función que la invoca

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

es para ver como podría hacer que una función me devolviera un valor para poder almacenarla en una variable y así usarla, esto lo quiero hacer para la validación del stock, ósea de que si no tengo stock pues entonces que no me guarde nada hasta que quite el articulo o renueve el stock agregando mas.

```
async function decreaseStock(idarticle,quantity){
    let {stock} = await models.Article.findOne({_id:idarticle});
    if(!stock || stock < 1){
        console.log('Stock empy');
        return false;
    } else {
        let nStock = parseInt(stock) - parseInt(quantity);
        await models.Article.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:idarticle},{stock:nStock});
        console.log('Stock plus');
        return true;
    }
}

export default {
    add: async (req,res,next) =>{
        try {
            //
            let details = req.body.details;
            details.map(function(x){
                decreaseStock(x._id,x.quantity);
                console.log(decreaseStock);
            })
            // const reg = await models.Sales.create(req.body);
            // res.status(200).json(reg);
            //
            res.status(200).json('Comnplete')
        } catch (e){
            res.status(500).send({
                message:'An error occurred'
            });
            next(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos.

RE: Saludos, en realidad no obtengo error, ese es el problema, pero ese pedazo de código es que tengo que corregir, cuando la funcion add llame la función decreaseStock que esta pueda devolverle un valor a la funcion add, ya que actúan separadas, con esto busco detener la funcion add en caso de que la funcion decreaseStock de algún problema.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a SOes. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Qué problema tienes con el código que pones en la pregunta? ¿Qué error encuentras? Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/418977/edit) tu pregunta e indica la respuesta a esto para saber cómo ayudarte :)

Comment: Saludos, en realidad no obtengo error, ese es el problema, pero ese pedazo de codigo es que tengo que corregir, cuando la funcion add llame la funcion decreaseStock que esta pueda devolverle un valor a la funcion add, ya que actuan separadas, con esto busco detener la funcion add en caso de que la funcion decreaseStock de algun problema.